# What are the possible ways to retrieve json values in MVC view?

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller, nvd3.js

I am using the following code in my view it gives a alert box as a json values.. Instead i need to put those json values in my code where i mentioned below.

```
    var option = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["choice"]));
    alert(JSON.stringify(option.Data)); 


    var data = [

        {

            values:/* here i need data*/

        }];

    var chart;
```

Its a nvd3 bar chart application please help me guys,,, or give me some methods to convert and pass json from mVC controller to view.

here is my code i cant figure out whats wrong in this code,

```
         <script type="text/javascript">

  var option = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["choice"]));

   var chart;
   var data=[{
    values: [

     @foreach(var item in option)
        {  
            <text>
            { 
                   "FullName": "@item.myfield1" ,
                   "ID": @item.myfield2
            } ,
            </text>
        }
       ]
      }];
    nv.addGraph(function () {
    var chart = nv.models.multiBarHorizontalChart()
      .x(function (d) { return d.FullName })
     .y(function (d) { return d.ID })
     .margin({ top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 50, left: 500 })
     .showValues(true)
      .tooltips(false)
          .showControls(false);

    chart.yAxis
   .tickFormat(d3.format(','));

    d3.select('#chart svg')
   .datum(data)
   .transition().duration(500)
   .call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    return chart;
    });

   </script>
```

Comment: Is the ASP?  Please see the tag wiki on [tag:mvc] for more info and tag appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can do like following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
...
var option = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["choice"]));
var chart;
var data=[
{
    values: option
 }];
...
</script>
```

In your controller you have to do like this to retrieve JSON data.

```
ViewData["choice"] = Json(listData).Data;
```

*listData is name of list containing your data.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do something like [this](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/discreteBar.html).

```
<script>
    .....
    var data=[{
    key:"My Key for Chart", 
     values: [
    @foreach(var item in option)
    {
    <text>
    { 
               "label" : "@item.myfield1" ,
               "value" : @item.myfield2
    } ,
    </text>
    }
    ]

    }];

    .....
</script>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Hi e2burner i got this error in the view                                        "The name 'option' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: just edited the code , be sure you are putting the code before you render your chart.